# importing other scripts from Boo script

Tags: import, unity-game-engine, boo

I'm having trouble referencing other scripts in my unity project from boo scripts. For example, SendMessage is a MonoBehavior I created elsewhere, doing this:

```
import UnityEngine

class MissionIcon (SendMessage): 

    def Start ():
        pass

    def Update ():
        pass
```

throws a "The name SendMessage does not denote a valid type (not found).
adding an

```
import SendMessage
```

throws a "Namespace SendMessage not found", adding

```
import SendMessage from Scripts.GUI.menus
```

(my script is under Assets/Scripts/GUI/menus) complains that that's not an assembly, and adding

```
import SendMessage from "Scripts/GUI/menus"
```

says the same thing. So.. how do I do this? Thanks and sorry about the total n00bness of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have to import script as any other unity asset.
Look at http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Asset%20Import%20and%20Creation.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK boo can't import script files.
You should import required namespace and add referenced file to booc.
Something like:

```
booc.exe file1.boo file2.boo
```